# Delphi XE6 - Problema de Driver Oracle

Tags: delphi-xe6

Bom dia amigos,

Recentemente comecei migrar umas fontes em delphi para C#, porém existem aplicações aqui na empresa que faz conexão com vários bancos, e um deles é oracle, porém o delphi da erro por não encontrar o driver de oracle, o Driver Ora do Oracle não aparece, alguém sabe me dizer se é um componente a parte ou uma configuração, pois não achei nada na internet, ou pesquisei errado.  O FireDAC Link que ta faltando é o TFDPlysORADriverLink.

Desde Já Obrigado.

Comment: Pelo que vi, tudo que é de Oracle não funciona no delphi kkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido! Era falta do FireDAC do update!